# Tig revert (checkout) single line / chunk

Tags: tig

Is there an option to revert changes from a single chunk in [Tig's](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/) Status View?

I mean functionality opposite to `u` or `1`.
I am aware of `!` operation, but this one reverts the whole file - not just a single change.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, open the stage view by pressing `Enter` in the status view, move to the chunk you want to revert and press `!`.

Comment: You are right - this works like `u`, great! But is there an option to revert just single line from the chunk (split it)?

Comment: No, there is not you have to first stage the whole diff chunk and then unstage the line using `1` _and then_ revert.

Comment: For others, who are getting the error `Unknown key, press h for help ` you need to create the `~/.tigrc` file and type: `bind main ! !?git revert %(commit)` and save. Then you can use `!` in you main view itself.

Comment: To revert means to revert an already committed change. In the stage view you can only see changes that are yet to be committed. I was more interested in knowing how can I pick a block of change from commit history and revert it.